# AttributeError with django-rest-auth and django-rest-knox - Token Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am currently setting up a django backend for a React frontend app.

As part of of, I am using django-rest-auth and django-allauth for registration and authentication. I wanted to implement better token management through django-rest-knox.

I used the following code to start from and modify my existing app with rest-auth and allauth (which works):

https://gist.github.com/AndrewPix/cdd9276b1d5683459b965d5cc4517b26

My problem is the following:

When I POST my credentials to the url /rest-auth/login, in the backend a token gets created for the right user, with all the attributes (e.g. expiry date), but I don't get the token and user returned as part of the API call. Instead I receive the below error:

AttributeError at /rest-auth/login/

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `token` on serializer `KnoxSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'token'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think something is wrong with the KnoxSerializer but I can't figure out what?

Thanks!

AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix came from the urls! Very simple late night mistakes. The URL path to KnoxLoginView was put after the inclusion of djang-rest-auth urls, instead of before.

By registering the URL `url(r'^rest-auth/login/', views.KnoxLoginView.as_view())` , and including that before the line     `url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls'))` , it works.